# Poitcut capturing annotation at both class and method levels

Tags: spring-aop

I am using Spring-AspetJ 3.2.11 support. I would like to have my aspect capture an annotation on the method level or on the class level, but spring does not seem to like the pointcut. Here is what I am trying, in this case ConvertRuntimeException is an annotation:

```
@Around( "execution(public * *(..)) and ( @within(uncaughtClass) or @annotation(uncaughtMethod) )" )
public Object execute(ProceedingJoinPoint jp, ConvertRuntimeException uncaughtClass, ConvertRuntimeException uncaughtMethod ) throws Throwable {
```

The error I get is:

```
WARN - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'convertRuntimeAdviceTest.TestConfig1': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 inconsistent binding
```

Everything works fine if I just use the class level pointcut (removing the or). I suppose I could do this with two separate bindings, but I would like the method to trump the class level. What is the best approach here?

Thanks,

Comment: check [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/aop/63617-problem-binding-multiple-params-with-target-and-within) and [this](http://code.google.com/p/easiest-cache-ever/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/googlecode/easiest/cache/ever/CacheAspect.java)